# python: mocking one class with another implementation

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Super basic mock question that is frustrating me, thanks for taking a look.

I have a class, say, `IngestionClient`, which implements some http requests to endpoints in another service. I need to mock these for tests.

In the past, when I didn't need the endpoints to actually do anything for tests, I simply did

```
@mock.patch('clients.IngestionClient.endpoint_1', return_value=Mocked200Response())
def test_update(endpoint_1):
    ...
```

But now I have a few more of these methods in the client, so each test has like four mock decorators, and I kind of need one of the methods to actually do something.

I'd like to implement a `MockedIngestionClient` class as something like

```
class MockedIngestionClient:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def endpoint_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Mocked200Response()

    def endpoint_2(self, row_id, new_value):
        with self.config.mysql_connector.get_mysql_session() as sess:
            row = sess.query(Table).filter_by(id=row_id)
            row.value = new_value
```

So that in tests I could do something like

```
@mock.patch('clients.IngestionClient', testing_utils.MockedIngestionClient)
def test_update(IngestionClient):
    ...
```

Is this possible? I know I could substitute IngestionClient with a MagicMock object and then add all the functions I need as one-offs but if it's possible to do it the way I described above that would feel cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the `new` parameter for patch.object:

```
def mocked_endpoint_2(self, *args):
    ...

@mock.patch.object(
    clients.IngestionClient,
    'endpoint_2',
    new=mocked_endpoint_2
)
```